# ajax call is not working in safari

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

this ajax call is working in chrome,IE,firefox,opera but not in safari.can anyone know the reason.

```
 var functionToCall = "CallUserControlFunctionAdd";
 var schoolInformation = JSON.stringify({ SchoolName: schoolName, schoolId: SchoolId, UserName: userName });


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "Account/MyAccount.aspx/" + functionToCall,
        data: schoolInformation,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function () {

        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
```

Comment: it's not showing any error.